# Stripe CLI: How to trigger events with nested metadata

Tags: command-line, stripe-payments, command-line-arguments

I'm using Stripe CLI to trigger local webhook events. The command lets me set metadata using the following option / syntax:

`--add resource:path1.path2=value`

The metadata structure I'm trying to create looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    artistId: 2,
    image: { 
        url: `https://somepath` 
    }
}
```

Here is my command:

```
$ stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded --add payment_intent:metadata.id=1 --add payment_intent:metadata.artistId=1 --add payment_intent:metadata.image.url=https://www.arweave.net/ij5O6dDlzxOuWHUnikZapq10kkeEVe_elLWvpfE6ado?ext=PNG
⣟ Checking for new versions... Setting up fixture for: payment_intent
Running fixture for: payment_intent
Trigger failed: Request failed, status=400, body={
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid value type: {:url=\u003E\"https://www.arweave.net/ij5O6dDlzxOuWHUnikZapq10kkeEVe_elLWvpfE6ado?ext=PNG\"} must be a string",
    "param": "metadata",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

At first, I thought that the `.` in the URL was breaking the syntax. But I get the same error when I substitute the URL with `foo`.

I think I must me doing something wrong with the path syntax. Or maybe there's a max limit to the depth of the data structure?

Update:

To sidestep this problem, I tried achieving the same thing using a [fixtures json file](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/fixtures) but it didn't work. I got the same error, even though the syntax is JSON and unambiguous. I contacted Stripe support and they also seemed confused by this behavior. I'm awaiting a response from their escalation team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe support confirmed that the metadata object can only have key / value pairs in which the values are strings. I was trying to use objects as values to create more complex data structures and this is not supported. :-(

Comment: you can store a JWT containing an object in your metadata

Comment: Or you could just stringify it and parse it back when metadata is read.

Answer (score 24):

if anyone coming here looking for a way to add multiple items in the metadata, you can do so by:

```
Stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded --add payment_intent:metadata['key']=testing --add payment_intent:metadata['key2']=testing2
```

Comment: The correct syntax for me in late 2022: To add `metadata = {'dog': 'cat'}`
Action:
`stripe trigger payment_intent.created --override payment_intent:metadata.dog=cat`

Comment: it works here, both `metadata[something]` and `metadata.something` syntax. CLI version 1.13.6

Answer (score 5):

This works also:

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded --add payment_intent:metadata.user_id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `.` in `image.url` key that's giving you problems.  The `.` indicates to go down a level, but metadata params can't be nested like that.

You can modify the key to an acceptable value such as `image_url` or `imageURL`, and that should resolve the error you're hitting.  (`image_url` did the trick for me)

Comment: Hi Toby. `image.url` is not the name of the key. It's supposed to be a nested object. The `image` object has a `url` property.

Comment: ...but I think you're definitely right about the `.` breaking the syntax. I guess the real question is how to pass deeper data structures. The docs show: `--add resource:path1.path2=value` which I understood to mean that at least some level of nesting is allowed. Is there a hard limit of two levels?